# Multiple UILabels on UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I am trying to control drop two UILabels onto a UIViewController. I keep receiving Cannot override strong property with weak property error.

Here is a short excerpt from my code. Here is a screenshot of all the errors https://gyazo.com/bd97fa42443d12a3aa17a2de55f78b60

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet private weak var display: UILabel!

@IBOutlet private weak var description: UILabel!

private var userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false

@IBAction private func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    if (digit == "c") {
        display.text = " "
    } else {
        print("touchDigit \(digit) digit")
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text
            if (sender.currentTitle!) == "c" {
                print("it printed c")
                display.text = "sam"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your `description` variable since `description` is the name of a method inherited from `NSObject` (the base class of `UIViewController`).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your UILabels with optional type `UILabel?` instead `UILabel!`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. This should be a comment.

Comment: In your post there is no questions. I explained you why have this advertise. And thats because you declare your Label with implicitly unwrapped property. There is your issue.